# How to do replace using sed only in one section of file

Tags: bash, sed

File looks like this:

```
[section1]
a=something
[section_name2]
a=something
[section3]
a=something
```

How do I replace `a=someother` only in `section_name2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an address range:

```
sed '/\[section_name2\]/,/^\[/ s/a=something/a=someother/'
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Changed it to sed '/\[section\]/,/^\[/ s/a=.*/a=someother/' and it working now

Comment: @arheops: Not sure how your changed command would have worked. First you are not escaping the [ and ]. Your first pattern /[section]/ will match any line which has one of s,e,c,t,i,o,n in it. Second you are using section instead of section_name2. I don't understand how that would work too.

Comment: All is working ok. Parser on this site remove escapes.